# py2app apps open slowly

Tags: python, wxpython, py2app

I created a Python application for OS X using py2app tool. Unfortunately, when I click the app, it launches on the dock, but the window appears 1-2 seconds later!
What is the problem and how can I avoid this?

What I do is:

1. py2applet --make-setup test.py
2. python setup.py py2app

I use wxPython for the GUI.

```
import os, sys, wx

def main():
    app = wx.App()

    frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Icon', pos=(350,300))
    #frame.SetIcon(wx.Icon('tipi.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO))
    frame.Center()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have the same kind of delay on windows. I'm not sure there is something to do about it. maybe reduce your import calls to the minimum?

Comment: On Windows the behavior is much worse when you pack everything as one big exe file. I am not sure about OS X. If that is the case, I can explain a bit more in detail.